# html parse with jquery.xdomainajax.js not working on PhoneGap

Tags: android, ajax, jquery, cordova, html-parsing

I am building a mobile app with Phonegap, using jquery.xdomainajax.js for parsing html elements from a url (another domain). The tutorial I'm following is [here](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide).

My application runs well in a web browser, but when I try it on android device was not running.

I've tried changing **super.setIntegerProperty ("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);** from **MyPhoneGapActivity.java**, but still failed.

and this my **index.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main-link.js"></script>


    <ul id="jquery_snippets">
      <li>Gathering News...</li>
    </ul>
```

and this my **main-link.js**

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> $.get('http://example.com', function(res) { 
>     $(res.responseText).find('.art-block2 h3').each(function() { 
>        var anchor = $(this).children('a:last');
>        jQuery('', { 
>          html: jQuery('', { 
>                  href: anchor.attr('href'),
>                  text: anchor.text() 
>               })
>        }).appendTo($('#jquery_snippets')); 
>      });
>
> $('#jquery_snippets li:first').remove();
>    });
>   });

What's the problem? (I'm using phoneGap 1.9.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a domain-whiltelist?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html